# Python Urllib2 doesn't return the whole file

Tags: python, html, urllib2

I'm trying to make a script so I can know when a page has some modifications (It can't be done with "Last-Modified" because the server replace the file with another identical after some days). So I was trying to use the Urllib2.urlopen() and .read() method to get a string which contains the code, like this:

```
try:
    file= open(filedir, 'w+')
    web = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    file.write(web.read())
except Error as e:
    print "Some error %s" % e
archivo.close()
```

Works fine, but when I try downloading the same page, I get the same but without some headers:

Reference file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> <html lang="es" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es"> <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>...
```

But when it comes to a new download, only get:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>...
```

The rest of the code are identical, but I want to know what it's happening. Thanks in advance.

NOTE: This happens when I run the script on the Python Console or Visual Studio, but if I run the script with "Sublime text" works fine.

Comment: I do not see any problem this code seems to be working fine.

Comment: Why? Shouldn't get the <!DOCTYPE ... header again the second time?